# How to delete files containing string from listbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete all files in the folder which names can not be found in listbox items. I assume i m missing a counter somewhere, but not really sure how to do this exactly.

```
Dim directoryName As String = "Folderimages"
For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  For Each item In ListBox1.Items
    Dim items As Object = ListBox1.Items
    Dim itemText As String = ListBox1.GetItemText(items)                
    If Not deleteFile.Contains(itemText) Then
      File.Delete(deleteFile)
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: The `items` and `itemText` declaration doesn't make any sense, since you are already iterating over the items inside `ListBox1` so what kind of items do you have inside `ListBox1`? Also note, you want to ensure that none of the items in the listbox match the filename, right now you are deleting a bit to early :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq, so your test will become easier:

```
Dim directoryName As String = "Folderimages"
For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  If Not ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().Any(Function(x) x = SearchString)) Then
    File.Delete(deleteFile);
  End If
Next
```

Did not try it, not sure if you need to cast the x as string.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a bit easier to split, the functionality you are creating here, just for easier usage aftewards

You can first have a function that gets all the items from your `ListBox`

```
Public Function GetItemsFromListBox( lbox as ListBox ) as IEnumerable(Of String)
    return from item in lbox.Items _
        select lbox.GetItemText( item )
End Function
```

And then have a function that retrieves all the files from a directory that are not inside that `IEnumerable(Of String)`

```
Public Function GetNonMatchingFiles( folder As String, nonMatchingItems As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return Directory.GetFiles( folder ) _
        .Where( Function(filename) not nonMatchingItems.Contains( Path.GetFileName( filename ), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
End Function
```

And then you can run through that result and delete the resultset. One thing to note would be that I compare the files with the filename only and not with the full path, if you don't want that, you should remove `Path.GetFileName` and just compare with `filename`, and that it will also look case insensitive

I didn't include the pattern (`*.*`) nor the searchoption as these are the defaults for that function anyhow